# Mass memory used, buffer free, no apps started

Tags: memory, buffer

Have searched for many times before asking for my problem.
I've 6gb RAM, 4 currently used, 2 free, buffers are low

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5982       4031       1951          0          2         16
-/+ buffers/cache:       4011       1971
Swap:  
   1023          3       1020
```

But my ps says no process ating this ram...

```
# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  19332   712 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:03 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:09 [migration/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:05 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [migration/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:28 [watchdog/0]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:02 [migration/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [migration/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:03 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:15 [watchdog/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:57 [events/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   1:07 [events/1]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [cgroup]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [khelper]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [netns]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [pm]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:03 [sync_supers]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:05 [bdi-default]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kintegrityd/1]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   1:33 [kblockd/0]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   1:25 [kblockd/1]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kacpid]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ata/0]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ata/1]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ata_aux]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ksuspend_usbd]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [khubd]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kseriod]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [md/0]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [md/1]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [md_misc/0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [md_misc/1]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        38  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   6:02 [kswapd0]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Jul01   0:00 [ksmd]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Jul01   2:43 [khugepaged]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [aio/0]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [aio/1]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [crypto/0]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [crypto/1]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kthrotld/0]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kthrotld/1]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [pciehpd]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [usbhid_resumer]
root        85  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kstriped]
root       234  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       235  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       243  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:12 [mpt_poll_0]
root       244  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [mpt/0]
root       245  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       309  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       330  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-0-8]
root       331  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       332  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root       677  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   2:24 [vmmemctl]
root       794  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       797  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       798  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       801  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       806  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       813  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       819  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       828  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       837  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       843  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       849  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       854  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       858  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       860  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       868  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       915  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       917  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       919  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       926  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       933  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root       936  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kdmflush]
root      1009  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/sda1-8]
root      1010  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1011  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1012  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-21-8]
root      1013  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1014  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1015  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-2-8]
root      1016  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1017  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1018  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-18-8]
root      1019  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1020  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1021  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-22-8]
root      1022  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1023  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1024  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:45 [jbd2/dm-19-8]
root      1025  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1026  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1027  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-17-8]
root      1028  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1029  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1030  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:08 [jbd2/dm-20-8]
root      1031  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1032  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1033  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:08 [jbd2/dm-3-8]
root      1034  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1035  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1036  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:03 [jbd2/dm-4-8]
root      1037  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1038  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1039  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:02 [jbd2/dm-5-8]
root      1040  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1041  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1042  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-6-8]
root      1043  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1044  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1045  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-7-8]
root      1046  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1047  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1048  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-8-8]
root      1049  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1050  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1051  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-9-8]
root      1052  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1053  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1054  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-10-8]
root      1055  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1056  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1057  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:23 [jbd2/dm-11-8]
root      1058  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1059  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1060  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-12-8]
root      1061  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1062  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1063  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-13-8]
root      1064  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1065  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1066  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-14-8]
root      1067  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1068  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1069  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:01 [jbd2/dm-15-8]
root      1070  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1071  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1072  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [jbd2/dm-16-8]
root      1073  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1074  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]
root      1134  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 [kauditd]
root      1538  0.0  0.0 248708   800 ?        Sl   Jul01   0:09 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 4
root      1559  0.0  0.0  64032   456 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      1607  0.0  0.0 117180   412 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:09 crond
root      1879  0.0  0.0   4048   204 tty2     Ss+  Jul01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      1881  0.0  0.0   4048   204 tty3     Ss+  Jul01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      1883  0.0  0.0   4048   204 tty4     Ss+  Jul01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      1886  0.0  0.0   4048   204 tty5     Ss+  Jul01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      1891  0.0  0.0   4048   204 tty6     Ss+  Jul01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
root      7598  0.0  0.0  97732  3816 ?        Ss   08:55   0:00 sshd: osadmin [priv]
osadmin   7603  0.0  0.0  97872  1956 ?        S    08:55   0:00 sshd: osadmin@pts/0
osadmin   7604  0.0  0.0 108324  1824 pts/0    Ss   08:55   0:00 -bash
root      8883  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    09:50   0:00 [flush-253:20]
root      8885  0.0  0.0 149440  1692 pts/0    S    09:51   0:00 su - root
root      8887  0.1  0.0 108448  1904 pts/0    S    09:51   0:01 -bash
root      8913  0.0  0.0   4048   540 tty1     Ss+  09:53   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      8971  0.0  0.0 110228  1116 pts/0    R+   10:03   0:00 ps aux
```

I've no idea wich process consume this ram.
A server reboot solve the problem for few hours/day.

I've already test :

- Cleaning buffer : `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
- Stop as much as possible process

Comment: Try using `top -o rsize` and `top -o vsize`.

Comment: I don't have the -o argument (top: unknown option 'o').

Comment: Then read the man page for top on your system to figure out how to make it sort the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running in a VMware virtual machine, and the VM has memory ballooning enabled. Thus the hypervisor can dynamically "take away" memory from your VM and allow other VMs to use it (since your VM is not using it). With VMware, this shows up as unaccountable "used" memory.